# Using asp.net how do I convert a comment script to to shout box

Tags: asp.net, chat, comments

I coded for a comment script in ASP.NET(C#) and now I want to turn it to a shout box. As the main difference between comment script and shout box is auto refresh. How refresh all client's pages on a new shout?

Answer (score 0):

Install a shout box widget

http://shoutbox.widget.me/